# Around a circular table

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways can $ 3 $ couples sit around a circular table in such a way that husband and wife are not together?

**My attempt:**

I tried to do it by circular permutation, then I found $ 120 $. In addition, I must subtract this amount from the restrictions, but I don't know how to calculate them

Answer is $ 32 $

Comment: Question: Do they have to alternate male, female, male, female etc around the table? [That would make a difference in the count.]

Comment: @MatthewDaly "The six seats are not numbered such that any rotation of a given configuration is regarded as the same configuration." Does it interfere with something in my problem, or does it make a difference?

Comment: Unless specifically mentioned otherwise, seats at a circular table are taken to be unnumbered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remembering that seating around an unnumbered circular table the permutations are $(n-1)!$ rather than $n!$ used for seating in a line, the simplest way to solve this problem is to  subtract from unrestricted arrangements, applying inclusion-exclusion,
gluing together $1,2,3$ couples together as "permutable pairs"

Thus $5! - \binom31 \cdot 2^1\cdot 4! +\binom32 \cdot2^2\cdot 3! -\binom33\cdot 2^3\cdot 2! = 32$

To explain the second term,

- one couple to sit together can be chosen in $\binom31$ ways
- they can be glued together in $2^1$ ways
- now there are $5$ **entities** that can be seated in a circle in $4!$ ways

Comment: $+1$ for clear answer

Comment: Thanks, glad you like it !